# Magento 2 replace fotorama with custom plugin with js on product page

Tags: magento2, plugin, fotorama-slider

Hi I have created jquery custom zoom gallery plugin. And want to replace default fotorama with mine on product page. For this purpose I want to use magento 2 plugin. Which I already started and created. It is just HelloWorld plugin yet for now.

Is it possible somehow to do this without touching core files or theme files. But only via magento 2 plugin system?

Thanks.